# How to rely on consistent data in the Google App Engine?

Tags: database, google-app-engine

We're making an iOS racing game with the app engine as backend. However in late June something strange happened (I just now got back from my vacation, hence I'm posting now).

The client posts scores and fetches highscore lists from the server and everything seemed to be working perfectly (we had been testing it for a month with no problems and the code is really simple with not much more than a put/get). But in late June, for a couple hours, old data was returned to the client. It happened for a while but then the data fixed itself.

However this still got us into trouble as on score submission we check that the server only has one highscore per player, but this app engine bug(?) caused the server to have multiple scores for some players.

So what happened was: Player A submits score, Player B submits score, data got reverted to when only Player A existed, Player B submits new score (it gets stored as server doesn't see a player B), server fixes data problem and now we have to Player B.

How should you go about if you want to be able to rely on the app engine's backend? This could be a deal breaker.

**To be more specific (As requested in the comments)**

I was simplyfying what we were doing a bit. But basically it's the same. So we're not just storing highscores, but also ghost data of players. Here's the code (but removed some extra fields that aren't relevant now).

Here's the model (with some non-important fields stripped):

```
class Highscore(db.Model):  
    player = db.StringProperty()  
    track = db.IntegerProperty()  
    track_time = db.FloatProperty()  
    ghost_data = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
```

And for storing, I first do a:

```
class GhostPrepareHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps({ 'add_highscore_url' : blobstore.create_upload_url('/api/highscore') }))
```

And then

```
class HighscoreUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
       # Check any previous highscore
       track = self.request.get('track')
       player = self.request.get('player')

       hs = Highscore.all().filter('track =', track).filter('player =', player).get()

       # Check if a previous ghost exists with a worse time, if so remove it,
       # else if previous time is better, do not store this highscore
       if hs is not None:
            if hs.track_time < float( self.request.get('track_time') ):
                self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
                self.response.out.write(json.dumps({ 'success' : True }))
                return

            hs.delete()

        # Store highscore
        hs = Highscore()
        hs.player = self.request.get('player')
        hs.track = int( self.request.get('track') )
        hs.track_time = float( self.request.get('track_time') )

        upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
        hs.ghost_data = upload.key()

        # Store
        hs.put()

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps({ 'success' : True }))
```

And then we got the read part

```
def get(self):
    player = self.request.get('player')
    track = self.request.get('track')

    highscores = HighScore.all().filter('track =', track).order('track_time').fetch(limit=4)

    highscores_json = []

    hs_count = 0
    for hs in highscores:
        # Filter out player or last ghost
        if hs.player == player or hs_count > 2:
            continue

        hs_obj = {
            'player' : hs.player,
            'track_time' : hs.track_time,
            'ghost_data_url' : 'http://' + host + '/api/highscore/download?ghost_key=' + str( hs.ghost_data.key() )
        }

        highscores_json.append( hs_obj )
        hs_count += 1

    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps( highscores_json ))
```

And it had been working fine, but for some reason, for a couple hours it returned old data (like days old data).

Comment: can you please add the code you use to query for seeing if there is any existing high score for a player and the score model? are you using memcache?

Comment: Yeah, at the very least show your models and the code you use to set/read your high score and user entities.  There's definitely opportunities for this to happen if you're not using transactions and ancestors.

Comment: I added some code (but stripped out a few parts). Not using memcache, that would explain it. It's an annoying problem we suffered from. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are retrieving scores via query then you have encountered [eventual consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) od HRD datastore. This happens because indexes (used for querying) are built asynchronously (= write operation returns before indexes are built).

Comment: But now it returned days old data for a few hours. Could it really be the same problem? Would be great if it was, then we'd know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a query to get one player's record for update? Sorry, just have time for a quick read, but it appears this is the case. I think it is safe to say you should never use queries for this type of update. You will hit issues with eventual consistency, and every get() is way more inefficient (latency) and high-cost (read/write-ops) than necessary. Why not write each player's highscore record with a unique id fashioned from his/her specific information? Then get_by_id(), and put(). You are guaranteed consistency, and the only limit is the limit of one write per second per record which should not be an issue in this case. Also, I would be very leery of relying on delete() like you do. If you used the get_by_id() process, you simply over-write the old hs with the new one with each put(). Again, if you are using this process to maintain each player's unique high score record, you really must re-architect it.